# In a MIP, how to force a decision variable to be zero unless the sum of specific other decision variables is equal to a certain number?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, modeling, integer-programming, logical-constraints

In an MIP, how can I formulate a constraint such that a decision variable is only greater (or equal to) zero if (and only if) the sum of different decision variables is equal to something.

I'm working with a path flow formulation model and I want to have a constraint that forces flow q on path p to be zero if not all routes in path p are flown.

Example: flow *q* on path *p*, which contains flight A to B ($f_{AB}$) and flight B to C ($f_{BC}$), can be greater than zero if and only if one aircraft flies from A to B and (the same or another aircraft) flies from B to C.

I) q = 0 if $\sum$($f_{AB}$ + $f_{BC}$) $\le$ 1

II) q $\ge$ 0 if $\sum$($f_{AB}$ + $f_{BC}$) = 2

In case there are three flights in one path, constraint I becomes $\le$ 2, and constraint II becomes = 3, etc.

(I know exactly which flow can go over which paths, and I know how many flights are contained in all of the available paths. Moreover, all $f_{ij}$ are binary)

Help with this would be highly appreciated! (I'm writing my problem in python, in case that matters for anything)

Comment: In II) you mean $q>0$ ? Otherwise you could have $q=0$ in both cases.

Comment: No q may still be zero. In general, there are multiple paths available for each q, so the fact that $f_{AB}$ and $f_{BC}$ are both 1, does not mean that this path will be used to transport q. I'm using a timespace network, so AB and BC do not only represent airports, but also points in time. Therefore, if a path earlier/later in time is better, then that other path can also be used.

Comment: In this case consider the answer below with $L:=0$.

Answer (score 5):

Introduce a binary variable $\delta \in \{0,1\}$ to indicate whether $q$ is positive or not. You want:
$$
\sum_{(i,j) \in A}f_{ij} \le |A| - 1 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \delta=0
$$
or the contrapositive:
$$
\delta=1  \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \sum_{(i,j) \in A}f_{ij} \ge |A| 
$$
which you can achieve with:
$$
\sum_{(i,j) \in A}f_{ij} \ge |A| \delta
$$

Then, assuming you want $q\ge L$ when $\sum_{(i,j) \in A}f_{ij} = |A|$, add the constraints:
$$
L\delta \le q \le M \delta
$$
$M$ is an upper bound on $q$. The right hand side of this last constraint enforces $q$ to take value $0$ when $\delta=0$.

Comment: Looks good (+1).  You can optionally strengthen the formulation by disaggregating the first constraint to $f_{ij} \ge \delta$ for all $(i,j)\in A$, which arises from rewriting $\delta \implies \wedge_{(i,j)} f_{ij}$ in conjunctive normal form.  Likely, cut generation will do this dynamically as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much @Kuifje! The constraint with the $\sum f_{ij} \ge |A| \delta$ works perfectly! (The constraint with $q \le M \delta$ I already had, with the upperbound being the maximum q can take on). 
@RobPratt I've added your cut as well, however, for some reasons it does not yet seem to improve the speed of convergence to an optimal solution (within a given timelimit of 15 minutes, the optimality gap is larger with this added cut, then without it) Do you think that a larger timelimit could make a change for the better?

Comment: No, I think that behavior is evidence that the useful cuts are generated as needed from the weaker aggregated constraint and that the other cuts just artificially make the LP larger.

Comment: if $\sum f_{ij} \geq |A|$ for example if $\sum f_{ij} =|A| $ then $|A| \geq |A|\delta \implies \delta \leq 1$ how does that force $\delta$ to be 1 ?

Answer (score 2):

With CPLEX you can use logical constraints.

For instance with the OPL API you can write:

```
dvar boolean q;
dvar int a;
dvar int b;

subject to
{
  q==(a+b>=2);
}
```

q is 0 iff a+b<=1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Interesting, I was not aware that this was possible. Will see if this can come of use in the future.